# cascading dropdown razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, cascadingdropdown

this is my code for cascading dropdown

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="CarChassis.CompanyNameId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="CarChassis.CompanyNameId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CompanyNameId"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CarChassis.CompanyNameId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label asp-for="CarChassis.CarModelId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="CarChassis.CarModelId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CarModelId"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CarChassis.CarModelId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

and code behind

```
 [BindProperty]
    public CarChassis CarChassis { get; set; }
    public int CarCompanyId { get; set; }
    public SelectList CarModelsList { get; set; }

    public  async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        ViewData["CarModelId"] = new SelectList(_context.CarModels, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["CompanyNameId"] = new SelectList(_context.CompanyNames, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["CreateYearId"] = new SelectList(_context.CreateYears, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["DiversityId"] = new SelectList(_context.Diversity, "Id", "Name");
        return Page();
    }
    public JsonResult OnGetCarMode(int CarCompanyI)
    {
       var CarModelsList = _context.CarModels.Where(x => x.CompanyNameId == CarCompanyI).ToListAsync();
        return new JsonResult(CarModelsList);

    }
```

also this is my Models

```
    public class CompanyName
{
  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
}
 public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public int CompanyNameId { get; set; }
    public CompanyName CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my ajax code

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CarChassis_CompanyNameId").on("change", function () {
            var CarCompanyI = $(this).val();
            $("#CarChassis_CarModelId").empty();
            $("#CarChassis_CarModelId").append("<option value=''>select </option>");
            $.getJSON(`?handler=CarMode&CarCompanyI=${CarCompanyI}`, (data) => {

                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#SubCategoryId").append("<option value='"+ item.id+ "'>" + item.name + "</option>");
                });
            
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

after run my code I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Comment: What is `#SubCategoryId`?Shouldn't it be `#CarChassis_CarModelId`?

Comment: yes it was my mistake but not related to my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problem in your code.

The first one is in your code(This is not an asynchronous method, `ToListAsync` cannot be used ):

```
var CarModelsList = _context.CarModels.Where(x => x.CompanyNameId == CarCompanyI).ToListAsync();
```

Change it to:

```
 var CarModelsList = _context.CarModels.Where(x => x.CompanyNameId == CarCompanyI).ToList();
```

The second one is in your ajax(`SubCategoryId` is not exist).

```
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#SubCategoryId").append("<option value='"+ item.id+ "'>" + item.name + "</option>");
            });
```

Change it to:

```
 $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#CarChassis_CarModelId").append("<option value='"+ item.id+ "'>" + item.name + "</option>");
            });
```

Comment: Thanks , my problem was async , why I can't use async??

Comment: `ToListAsync` need `await` keyword and need in a asynchronous method.

Comment: You can use this code:`public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetCarModeAsync(int CarCompanyI)
        {
            var CarModelsList =await _context.CarModels.Where(x => x.CompanyNameId == CarCompanyI).ToListAsync();
            return new JsonResult(CarModelsList);
        }`